# How to change user-group in apache?

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I am using apache server for deploying php web application and creating one directory using following code.

```
<?php  
   mkdir (tmpdir);
?>
```

but i found its user is www-data.

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data     54 Mar 20 15:22 tmpdir
```

but i chnaged the username to user using follwoing command

```
sudo chown -R user:user /var/www
```

resatrted the apache server but still same user exists.May i know, how can i change the user?

Comment: what user in your httpd.conf?

Comment: Can you confirm ownership / group of targets after running `chown` command?

Answer (score 1):

You will find in `httpd.conf` `User` and `Group` change its values to what you want 
Please read this [link](https://docs.oseems.com/general/application/apache/change-user-and-group)